# Printing out adjacent numbers in a list that have at least one common digit between them

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, integer

I have a list of natural numbers and I need to print out every two adjacent integers that have at least one digit in common. So far I've written:

```
for i in range(len(my_list) - 1):
    first, second = my_list[i], my_list[i+1]
    if first==second and first>0 and second>0:
        print(first, second)
    else:
        print("nothing")
```

but, as you can see, it's missing the integer part. I've thought about dividing integers and working with results, but I'm certain that's not going to work.

Comment: Please show an example list of numbers and outputs

Answer (score 3):

This is one place where strings can be quite effective. You can convert the string representation of an integer into a set, which can then be compared to another set. If the intersection is non-empty, they share a digit:

```
if set(str(first)) & set(str(second)):
    # first and second share a digit
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm a total newbie and I had heard about converting integers to strings!

Answer (score 2):

Try using `enumerate()` for slightly cleaner loop semantics.

Once you have `this_n` and `next_n`, decompose the integers into strings to get the digits as chars.  Then, use a `set` to distinctly count the individual digits of each string, and use its `intersection()` method to see if two the sets have common elements:

```py
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

for i, this_n in enumerate(numbers[:-1]):
    next_n = numbers[i+1]
    these_chars = set(str(this_n))
    next_chars = set(str(next_n))
    if these_chars.intersection(next_chars):
        print(this_n, next_n)
```

When I run that, I get:

```
10 11
11 12
```

Comment: Better yet: `for a, b in zip(numbers, numbers[1:]):` for a one-liner, or `itertools.tee` if you want a longer, more efficient implementation.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Hmm, should be `for a, b in zip(numbers[:-1], numbers[1:])`, right? I'm still leaning towards my code for read-ability, but thank you for sharing. :)

Comment: `zip` will terminate with the shortest iterable, so you can be lazy. Aside from that, your understanding is exactly correct. My comment was meant to be just that (a comment), and not a suggestion for your answer. You have my +1

Answer (score 0):

you can use zip to pair items with their successors in a list comprehension.  Then select the pairs for which there is an intersection between the sets of digits of the two numbers.  You can use `set(str(n))` to get the set of digits of a number:

```
numbers = [1,234,325,987,108,999]

print([ (a,b) for a,b in zip(numbers,numbers[1:]) if set(str(a))&set(str(b)) ])

[(234, 325), (987, 108)]
```